# An animation of 2D character in Vue.js, problem with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, vue.js

I found a new way for me how to create animations in Vue.js - 2D character [here is a picture](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DGqel6Ed4LpY&psig=AOvVaw2xJQEY2zUv_nV8ajvKTogl&ust=1603882272154000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCOCXoZ3N1OwCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD) The progress: you gonna move each one character in that picture each specific time. The solution: you gonna see the character moving.

I have created my own character. I want to change the animation of this character after the `numTotal > 0`. Exactly what I want to do: My main animation is called `idle`, when `numTotal > 0` a want to change animation to `angry`, after 2 seconds the animation should switch back to my animation `idle`

Vue.js

```
<div class="character" :style="inlineStyle"></div>
```

Data

```
data() {
      return {     
          animationDelay: 2000,
          angry: 'animation-name: angry',
          idle: 'animation-name: idle',
          currentAnimation: null,
          afterAnimation: null,
          animation: null,
      }
    },
```

Computed

```
computed: {
        inlineStyle() {
            if (this.numTotal > 0) {

                this.updateAnimation(this.animation, this.angry, this.idle)
                return this.animation


            } else {
                this.animation = this.idle
                return this.animation
            }
        }
    },
```

Methods

```
    methods: {
        updateAnimation(animation, currentAnimation, afterAnimation){
            animation = currentAnimation

            setTimeout(() => {
                animation = afterAnimation
            }, 500)
        },
```

Style

```
.character {
    background-image: url("http://huwe_final.test/images/character-animation.png?7b1c86288eb21d80e5981e0693e08d5e");
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 93%;
    height: 747px;
    margin-left: 3px;;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: steps(24);
    animation-duration: 1.2s;
}
@keyframes idle {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: -11782px 0; }
}
@keyframes angry {
    from { background-position: 0 745px; }
    to { background-position: -11782px 745px; }
}
```

The problem which I have is that my `setTimeout` is not working even when I write in console animation - `console.log(animation)`, I see that the `animation` has change to `angry`, but at the website the animation is still `idle`

Does anyone know how to fix `setTimeout`?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why do you dont set `this.animation` inside the timeout ? Would it be possible for you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: I update the question to an easier way. I put  `this.animation`inside the timeout cause I wanted after 500ms change animation to `idle` from `angry`. It was the only idea I had how to switch the animation.

Comment: But your write only "animation" not "this.aniation" that was my question, and outside the timeout you use "this.animation"

Comment: Now I see it. I have changed it everywhere to `this.animation` and into to computed I called the method without `animation`. 
Here is it, how my code looks like in section in Methods: `updateAnimation(currentAnimation, afterAnimation){
     this.animation = currentAnimation
      setTimeout(() => {
      this.animation = afterAnimation
       }, 500)
            console.log(this.animation)
        }`

But it's still not working. This time it's just changed the animation to `angry` and it didn't switch back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure, whats wrong with your snippet, since you removed more and more i cant see any errors.

But this should absolute work. See my minimal example:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .red {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .blue {
            background-color: blue !important;
        }

        .green {
            background-color: green !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="example">
        <div id="bar" v-bind:class="animation">
            {{ hello }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#example',
            data() {
                return {
                    hello: "background-div",
                    animation: "green"
                }
            },
            methods: {
                gainAttention(newVal) {

                    let last = this.animation;
                    this.animation = newVal;

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.animation = last;
                    }, 1000);

                }
            },
            mounted() {

                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.gainAttention("red");
                }, 3000);

                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.gainAttention("blue");
                }, 5000)

            }
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you post the animations/css i put them for you together.

Comment: So I update the code ( I tried to make it as simple as possible, but there is a lot of important parts). If you can somehow put it together it would be great. Anyway, thank's for the example code. I gonna tried it with your example.

Comment: `http://huwe_final.test/images/character-animation.png?7b1c86288eb21d80e5981e0693e08d5e` does not load

Comment: Here is the link of the photo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ks7BO8PHufgkBaKlMt_0RAPbqLlGpUW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ou man :D Do you have any specific ideas about how to adjust CSS? Maybe we don't have to work with my picture, it's gonna be okay if we use for example `background-color`, would it have the same result as if we use my picture?

Comment: It's finally working. I used what did you use - two times setTimeout. It's great, thank you! But now I have a different problem. First setTimeout have set up the time `500` and the second setTimeout have set up the time `1750` (cause of the duration of the animation). The animation is done for the first time; it looks great, the animation continues, but it seems like it's working at a different time set up. After a few second animations is switching every one second. I don't understand why it's doing this. Can you help with this, please?

Comment: I hope you understand what I just wrote.

Comment: It needs like a `break` or something familiar, which would stop the animation and switch to the first animation. I'm not sure if there is something like a `break`. There is definitely some way how to do it. Can you help me?

Comment: Lets start a chat here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223747/users-14527593-andy

Comment: I must have 20 reputations to talk at that website. I have only 11.

Comment: Can you please edit your question, add a horizontal bar (---------) and add a "new" question below with your current code. i edit then my answer too

Comment: Buddy, it's finally working. I really appreciate your help. Without your code which you sent, I wouldn't make it. Thank you very much!

Comment: If it works, can you please mark my answer, so other people are helped when the find the question